# Mount linux partition as Windows network share over internet

Tags: linux, windows, networking, mount, drive

I have a Linux server running RHEL 6. I have two Windows servers. All servers are connected directly to the web with an external IP, they are not in a local lan.

What I would like to achieve is to setup the Linux server so that it offers a single share (the whole partition) that can be mounted as network drive within Windows. I don't want to use any 3rd party software to access the linux server because I want to use the linux server as a backup for Bare Metal Restore. In order to do so, I need to be able to access the linux partition from within the Windows Recovery Enviroment where I cannot install any 3rd party software.

The linux server should only be accessible from given IP addresses (e.g. the 2 windows servers).

Does anyone know if the setup I would like to have is possible?

Comment: How about sharing out via iSCSI?

Answer (score 0):

Samba and iptables plus a kind of VPN which would make secure connection for this network filesystem (cifs from Samba). For VPN check IPSEC implementation of strongswan.

Comment: Thanks Jiri, but I can't use VPN either from recovery environment

Comment: Samba + IPTables can be resonably secure.

Comment: Plus you can simply disable the Samba share or samba completely until the need arises to map the drive in Windows PE.  But I hope the connection is fast and the bare metal restore isn't crazy huge.  How the OP plans on keeping the image up to date is interesting as well.

Answer (score 0):

Apache + Mod_DAV => Map Network Drive in Windows

Comment: + iptables.  webdav is prone to being hacked.